# Can someone make this a single query?

Tags: asp-classic, ado

So I was just searching how to do an "INSERT INTO" query and found this:

```
    sql="INSERT INTO Customers (ID,firstName,"
    sql=sql & "lastName)"
    sql=sql & " VALUES "
    sql=sql & "('" & Request.Form("id") & "',"
    sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("firstname") & "',"
    sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("lastname") & "')"
```

I know it works but I want to make it a single query without all the sql=sql's

Comment: So your question is about string concatenation and not about ado?

Comment: Uhm, I guess so. I'm new to ADO queries and all.

Comment: Look at parameters, the above is not a good idea at all.

Comment: @rene I fear it's classic ASP, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21705266/can-somebody-explain-how-this-asp-code-works).

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for:
`sql="INSERT INTO Customers (ID,firstName,lastName) VALUES ('" & Request.Form("id") & "','" & Request.Form("fistname") & "','" & Request.Form("lastname") & "')"`

Comment: You do realize that your solution still leaves you with a sql injection ?

Comment: The site will never go online. It is just for me to learn. I want to learn the basics first before thinking about security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You took the route of a quick hack as stated in your comments by doing rhis:

```
sql="INSERT INTO Customers (ID,firstName,lastName) VALUES ('" & Request.Form("id") & "','" & Request.Form("fistname") & "','" & Request.Form("lastname") & "')"
```

Let me persist in stating that to prevent several issues  (sql injection being one of them) you could leverage the use of paramterized queries.
I assume you have an ADO command somewhere after your sql statement. It is much safer if you use command parameters to send parameters from the website to the query.

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customers (ID,firstName,lastName) VALUES (?,?,?)"

Set param = command.CreateParameter ("id", adInteger, adParamInput)
param.value = Request.Form("id") 
command.Parameters.Append param 

Set param2 = command.CreateParameter ("firstname", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50)
param2.value = Request.Form("firstname") 
command.Parameters.Append param2 

Set param3 = command.CreateParameter ("lastname", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50)
param3.value = Request.Form("lastname") 
command.Parameters.Append param3 

command.Execute
```

Have a look at [Command Object Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more background.

Answer (score -5):

You can do like this:

`string sql = string.Format("INSERT INTO Customers(Id,FirstName,LastName) VALUES({0},'{1}','{2}')", param0, param1, param2);`

It Works! But be careful this way have SQL Injection issues.

Comment: This has a major sql injection issue

Comment: @ViniciusB.Bizarri did you try to run this code with dummy table? Try, and see what happens.

Comment: Now it works but OP explicitly asked how to do that without messing around with quotes. So still no real gain here.

Comment: I'm not downvoting, but for anyone reading, this is C# and not Classic ASP (vbscript) so it'll never work for this question.