# VBA ADODB Error -2147217904 - Values were not specified for some of the required parameters

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, adodb

In an Excel VBA project I'm using an .accdb Access DB, along with ADODB.Connection for performing queries, etc. My system has MS Office 2007 (English), but the client's system is Office 2010 (Spanish).

I've tested on my machine, and the queries, inserts, etc. all work fine. But when I tested on the client's machine, I got the following error:

> Error -2147217904, No se han especificado valores para algunos de los parámetros requeridos.

Which can be translated, roughly, to "Values were not specified for some of the required parameters."

The statement giving me problems is the following, executed using `conn.Execute sql, numRowsAffected`:

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable
    (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6, COL7, COL8, COL9, COL10, COL11, COL12, COL13, COL14)
    VALUES (1, 'TEXT', 5163, 8482, 103, Verdadero, 3, -1, 'Blanco', 3, 33, 40, 29, 1);
```

I've changed column names to shorten the code. Also, `Verdadero` is `True` in Spanish, in case anyone's wondering.

I've searched for this error on the web, but I can't find much useful information. [One forum](http://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/Visual_Basic/1325594-no_se_han_especificado_valores_para_algunos_de_los_parametros_requeridos.html) (in Spanish) mentioned that the error usually means that a field name is wrong, like a table column name changed from "Persona" to "Person", but the query is still referencing "Persona". I double checked, and I don't think this is the case here. Furthermore, the query executes perfectly on my system, which wouldn't be the case if it were a problem like this.

It's also worth noting that other inserts execute successfully (on the client's machine), and the error is only experienced when it executes this particular statement. Also, `SomeTable` has an `AUTOINCREMENT` PK ID value that is not included in the SQL statement above.

I assumed that 2007 VBA would be compatible with 2010, and that the clients' machines having the Spanish version of Office wouldn't matter, but now I'm having doubts. I'm using references to "Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library", while the client's is 14.0, and Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.0 Library, while the client's is 6.1 (I think). Same for the Access database engine Object Library, mine is 12.0 and client's is 14.0.

Anyone know of any potential causes?

Comment: Looks like the problem is with `Verdadero` which is not wrapped in single quotes, hence considered a parameter... and indeed, you don't give it any value in the code. Wrapping it with single quotes, like you already wrap other fields, will fix the error.

Comment: Not if col6 is a boolean field @ShadowWizard...in that case the bool to string conversion should not be localized.

Comment: On that conn.execute can't you provide the values in the Parameters collection instead of a buildup sql (because I assume that is what you are doing)?

Comment: COL6 is a boolean (bit) field. In the method, the value being assigned comes from a VBA `Boolean` data type. On my machine it shows up as `True` (no quotes)...on the client's machine it shows as `Verdadero` no quotes. Could this still be an issue?

Comment: Access SQL ignores other regional settings like date formats, number formatting (decimal separator, etc.) so I would not be surprised if it ignored the language setting as well. A Spanish version of Access might localize `True` as `Veradero` **for VBA**, but I would not be at all surprised if Access SQL only "spoke English" and had no idea what `Veradero` meant.

Comment: @rene you assumed correctly, the method concatenates an sql string based on an array of values. I'll try the Parameters collection and see what happens.

Comment: @GordThompson So a possible (but not pretty) work-around could be to replace `Verdadero` values with `True` in the concatenated string? (If, in fact that is the problem.) And, would using the Parameters collection make this a moot point (although I can figure this out with a little reading)?

Comment: I would only do the replace if this is a hot/urgent/life threatening produxtion issue. The parameter collection will fix it for almost 99% sure

Comment: Much better to use a parameterized query anyway. If the Spanish VBA word for `True` is `Veradero` and internally the parameter is just a Boolean then Access SQL won't know (or care) what the VBA language environment is.

Comment: Have a look at an answer I gave yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21732435/578411

Comment: @GordThompson and rene. Thanks for your help. I didn't forget about you, I just didn't have access to a client (Spanish) computer until today. For a quick fix I did a replace of "Verdadero" with "True" (and same for "Falso" -> "False"), and the error disappeared. Now I'll implement with command params. As a side note, I'll mention that I already noticed I have a similar issue with numbers (comma vs. period decimal separator), although that one doesn't generate an error, it just processes data incorrectly. Should be fixable with a `Replace`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments to the question, this appears to be yet another example of where a *parameterized query* will make code easier to manage (as well as safer). In this case the code would look something like this:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub InsertTest()
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection, cmd As ADODB.Command
    Const Veradero = True  ' to simulate Spanish VBA environment
    Set con = CurrentProject.Connection
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    cmd.ActiveConnection = con
    cmd.CommandText = _
            "INSERT INTO SomeTable (TextField, YesNoField) VALUES (?,?)"
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, "TEXT")
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", adBoolean, adParamInput, , Veradero)
    cmd.Execute
    Set cmd = Nothing
    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```